# Publishing updates via web deploy to Azure web app, confused on process and time it takes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

This may seem like a stupid question but I've been deploying updates to a development site for a project I adopted using a web deploy publishing profile.

This always takes 15 minutes or so.

However, I wanted to test a more realistic example so in order to take the app offline I followed these instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ee942158(v=vs.110)#how-to-automatically-take-an-app-offline-during-deployment

So I pushed another update and kept refreshing the development site and sure enough, it showed under construction, but only for about 1 minute, and then it was back up.

However, even as I type this question, almost 15 minutes later Visual Studio is still rattling out line by line of publishing updates in the build output window.

Can someone help me understand the lifecycle of web deploy publish from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that it dues to WebApp that does not enable `Always on` .

> By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time.

You could have a try to enable [Always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings) and try it again.

If you want to understand web deploy you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/deploying-web-applications-in-enterprise-scenarios/application-lifecycle-management-from-development-to-production).

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your answer but this is not related to a web app unloading or being idle. It's regularly used.